# Chrome GCM Push Show with big image

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Does anybody know how to send GCM pushes with big images like this example?

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAyRW.png)

I have looked for documentation, but there is no much information about web GCM pushes :(